# What is Chronic Cerebral Small Vessel Ischemic disease?

Tags: brain, disease

I am curious.  What is chronic cerebral small vessel ischemic disease? Does anyone have any suggestions for someone with that disease?  What is the life expectancy?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalScience.SE! On top of what @CareyGregory pointed out, [for a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748), we can not, and will not, give medical advice. If you or someone else has a question regarding personal health, the advice from a doctor should be sought. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta].